# The algebra of smooth functions as a projective tensor product

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, locally-convex-spaces

In [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/123879) quesiton it is mentioned that the algebra of smooth functions from a compact Manifold $M$ to a Frechet space $F$ is isomorphic to the projective tensor product $C^{\infty}(M) \otimes_\pi F$, i.e.

$$
C^{\infty}(M) \otimes_\pi F \cong C^{\infty}(M, F)
$$

Do you have references to that result? Do I have to assume that $F$ is a Frechet space for this to hold, or does it hold for arbitrary locally convex vector spaces?

Comment: I found a similar result in page 533 of the book [Topological vector spaces, distributions and kernels by Francois Treves][1], where they used $C^{\infty}(X)$ for $X$ an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ instead of $C^{\infty}(M)$. 


  [1]: https://shop.elsevier.com/books/topological-vector-spaces-distributions-and-kernels/treves/978-1-4831-9859-0